# set value for a column with dynamic name in python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following defined table in Python sqlalchemy:

```
class entry(Base):
    summary = Column(String(10000))
    content = Column(String(10000))
    description = Column(String(10000))
```

And I basically want to do the following:

```
a = entry()
for col in ['summary', 'content', 'description']:
    a[col] = get_value(col)
```

But I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'entry' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So I guess I cannot treat `a` as a `dict`. Looking through sqlalchemy document, I didn't figure out a way to set the value of a `Column` when using a variable to identify the `Column`. Could anyone point me to the right direction? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
a = entry()
for col in ['summary', 'content', 'description']:
    setattr(a, col, get_value(col))
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will not raise any exception if you try to set a column that does not exist in the model.